# How to sort dates in increasing order within a row in a dataset

Tags: r, sorting

So I am trying to do a simulation of my data,and my dataset includes dates variables. I was able to generate random dates for these variables. All the dates are within a period from x to y. However, I need to make sure that for each observation the date in column 3 is before the date in column 5, so on and so forth.

This is the code I used to generate the dates for each variable:

```
sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"),50)
```

So my question is how to go through each row and make sure the dates are in ascending order?

[image: This is a screenshot of my dataset]

Thank you :))

Comment: Hi, this is a coding platform, please don't use images, rather copy-paste your code or data, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? If this is your goal I can annotate the code so it is easier to understand. Also, in the future, it is a good practice to include a reproducible example of your code when you post a question.

```
set.seed(123)

df1 = data.frame(id = 1:50, 
                 date_1 = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"),50),
                 var_1 = sample(1:50, 50),
                 date_2 = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"),50),
                 var_2 = sample(1:50, 50),
                 date_3 = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"),50),
                 var_3 = sample(1:50, 50))

date_pos <- grepl("date", names(df1))

df1[date_pos] <- t(apply(df1[date_pos], 1, sort))

head(df1)
  id     date_1 var_1     date_2 var_2     date_3 var_3
1  1 2012-09-02     3 2013-01-05    43 2015-03-15    13
2  2 2013-05-01    22 2016-07-08    25 2017-09-26    11
3  3 2013-11-11    39 2014-06-02    19 2015-03-18    29
4  4 2014-08-08     6 2017-03-06    12 2017-09-04    50
5  5 2013-10-25    26 2014-05-18     6 2017-07-29    25
6  6 2011-04-27    10 2017-02-25    18 2017-03-23    36
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But it is not working for me it gave me this error message Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date_pos, value = list(c(date_ab_ag_posresult = "2011-06-23", : replacement element 2 has 7 rows, need 50

Comment: Can you post `dput(head(your_data))` as an edit to your question? Or the code you used to create the data.

Comment: I used this code "for(i in 1:50) {data_hcv[i,date_pos] <- sort(data_hcv[i,date_pos])}" instead of the t(apply()) and it worked. Thanks